# create Date object from year, month, day AND time

Tags: java, date

Is it possible to create a `java.util.Date`object from year, month, day AND time?

I am using this code:

```
private Date convertToDate(LocalTime time)
{
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Instant instant = time.atDate(LocalDate.of(date.getYear(),
           date.getMonth(), date.getDay())).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
    return Date.from(instant);
}
```

The problem I am facing is that this code always adds 6 minutes and 32 seconds to my time.
So if my `LocalTime time` is e.g. `08:00`the created Date is `Mon Sep 03 08:06:32 CET 115`.

Comment: What's the type of the 'date' variable and why is it not local? Was it supposed to be 'time' ?

Comment: what is "date"? And what is the purpose of your code, does not make any sense to me

Comment: This method is part of a time record application, where the date is part of the class attributes. `date` is a `java.util.Date`. `time` is a time in the time record, but I need it as a `java.util.Date`

Comment: @Jbartmann Please clean up your code example rather than explaining in comments. If `date` is a java.util.Date you could explain that by passing it as a second declared argument for our benefit.

Comment: Explaining the 06:32 mystery might be helped by posting here the result of getting your JVM’s current default time zone.  Call [`TimeZone.getDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault--) and [`ZoneId.systemDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault--).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [`Date#getYear`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getYear%28%29) wrongly:

> Returns a value that is the result of subtracting 1900 from the year
>   that contains or begins with the instant in time represented by this
>   Date object, as interpreted in the local time zone.

`getYear()` has an offset of 1900, which you have to add when using `LocalDate.of(year, month, day)`. That's why the year of your calculated Instant is 115.

```
Instant instant = time.atDate(LocalDate.of(date.getYear() + 1900,
       date.getMonth(), date.getDay())).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
```

Comment: This solved my issue though I have no clue why. All you did was adding 1900 to the year, but now the 6 minutes and 32 seconds are gone. Thanks!

Comment: It's because pinning an `LocalDateTime` to an instant in the timeline via `atZone` takes into account that there may have been some historical time-adjustment actions. For an specific explanation you may ask a new question. Digging into the correct procedure is very time consuming, but I'm sure there are some experts on SO ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative solution using a one-liner without deprecated methods:

```
return Date.from(date.toInstant()
                     .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                     .with(time)
                     .toInstant());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the date and the time, use the `LocalDateTime` class.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(18, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(42, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        long time = hours + minutes + seconds; // 6:30:42 PM
        Date date = toDate(2015, 10, 13, time);
        DateFormat dateFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d yyyy  hh:mm:ss a");

        System.out.println(dateFmt.format(date)); // Oct 13 2015  06:30:42 PM
    }

    public static Date toDate(int year, int month, int date, long time) {
        int hour = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(time) % 24;
        int minute = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(time) % 60;
        int second = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(time) % 60;
        int milli = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(time);

        return toDate(year, month, date, hour, minute, second, milli);
    }

    public static Date toDate(int year, int month, int date) {
        return toDate(year, month, date, 0);
    }

    public static Date toDate(int year, int month, int date, int hour) {
        return toDate(year, month, date, hour, 0);
    }

    public static Date toDate(int year, int month, int date, int hour, int minute) {
        return toDate(year, month, date, hour, minute, 0);
    }

    public static Date toDate(int year, int month, int date, int hour, int minute, int second) {
        return toDate(year, month, date, hour, minute, second, 0);
    }

    public static Date toDate(int year, int month, int date, int hour, int minute, int second, int milli) {
        return toDate(LocalDateTime.of(year, month, date, hour, minute, second, milli));
    }

    public static Date toDate(LocalDateTime timestamp) {
        return Date.from(timestamp.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use Calendar class

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.clear();
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

Comment: Really? He is using a LocalTime (Java 8?) and you suggest he uses a Calendar? And where is the time in all that?